# Convert float to string without losing precision

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

I want to store a float value into string without lossing or adding any single precision digits.

For example if my float value is 23.345466467 , I want my string to have str = "23.345466467" exact digits.

I tried using CString format function with %f. Its giving only first 6 precision.
or if i use %10 , if my float value is having less than 10 precision,its adding some more junk precision. I want to get exact float value into my string. how to do this?

Comment: That would depend upon whether your float value 23.345466467 is exactly representable (likely not)

Comment: @Mitch: I was wondering the same thing. What would be the simplest way to check if it is?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: A `float` value is always representable as a string as long as the base you convert to is divisible by 2.  Of course  `23.345466467` is not representable by a `float` in the first place.

Comment: Your requirement is as impossible as representing 1/3 exactly as a decimal string.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

1st of all: you can't convert floating to string and back without probably loosing a bit or two. As it is not 1-to-1 conversion as they use different base.

For preserving the best accuracy for floating point type:

```
std::string convert(float value)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10+1);
  ss << value;
  return ss.str();
}
```

Or more generic

```
template<typename FloatingPointType>
std::string convert(FloatingPointType value)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<FloatingPointType>::digits10+1);
  ss << value;
  return ss.str();
}
```

It would cut off digits you do not need but keep highest precision possible.

Comment: If i keep highest precision, For example : if i use digits10+10, For the value 213.2352352345345346f ; its returning 213.2352294921875; I didn't understand why the junk digits are coming after 4 digit precision.

Comment: @Rajesh, this is because the number you want cannot be exactly represented by a `float` see the comments on your question. If it cannot be represented, it simply cannot be represented, there is very little you can do about it! You need to consider another approach, may be integral exponent/mantissa?

Comment: Shouldn't this be digits10+2?  I wrote a quick test program and only +1 seemed to not allow me to round trip the floating point number through the string.  +2 seemed to work for big and small numbers though.

Comment: Indeed for `float` it must be `digits10+2` -- see http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/ .

Comment: This answer is absolutely wrong. Yes, you can convert a float to a string and back without losing "a bit or two". These are computers we are dealing with, not approximations scratched into sand. For float in C/C++ you need to printf with %1.8e or %.9g. When you convert back you will retrieve exactly the same value.

The value printed may not match what you see in your debugger, and likely neither represents the exact float value but they identify it uniquely. See my blog post for full details:

http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/float-precision-revisited-nine-digit-float-portability/

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian Please change this answer's status as the correct answer. It's opening sentence is completely wrong. Round-tripping is entirely possible as I said in my previous comment. Hugues answer looks much better.

Comment: @BruceDawson Sorry if this is a dumb question... But if youre going to print with this non readable format, isnt it better to just print the binary value as hexadecimal?

Comment: This answer is wrong (you don't inevitably lose a bit or two) so you'd be better served by commenting on one of the answers that is correct.
I don't know what you mean by this "non readable format" however. Decimal scientific notation is quite readable.

Answer (score 12):

See the nice detailed discussion in http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/ .

The short answer is that the minimum precision is the following:

```
printf("%1.8e", d);  // Round-trippable float, always with an exponent
printf("%.9g", d);   // Round-trippable float, shortest possible
printf("%1.16e", d); // Round-trippable double, always with an exponent
printf("%.17g", d);  // Round-trippable double, shortest possible
```

Or equivalently, with a `std::ostream& os`:

```
os << scientific << setprecision(8) << d;    // float; always with an exponent
os << defaultfloat << setprecision(9) << d;  // float; shortest possible
os << scientific << setprecision(16) << d;   // double; always with an exponent
os << defaultfloat << setprecision(17) << d; // double; shortest possible
```

Comment: Also see this post for more details:

http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/float-precision-revisited-nine-digit-float-portability/

Answer (score 10):

That would depend upon whether your float value 23.345466467 is exactly representable (likely not)

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

[Why Floating-Point Numbers May Lose Precision](https://web.archive.org/web/20140223010824/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx)

I would also question why you need to do this?  What are you going to use the string representation for?  Are you aware of the double and decimal types?

[***Untested***: you could try casting to double and then using "%d" Maybe this will pull in the extra 'guard' digits' but it still won't work for all values]

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I want to store the float value into xml, for this purpose i am converting into string. I want to read back the exact float value.  My issue is when converting from float to string i am lossing precisions. I want the exact precisions back. How to do this?

Comment: That says what you are doing, but not why.

Comment: I am reading float value from device.After some point of time i will be writing the same value to device.If a sigle precision changed, the device won't accept it.

Comment: You can store it in 32-bit hex instead if you want 100% precision. Edit: oh, that's exactly what pmg suggested.

Answer (score 9):

C99 supports the `%a` format in `printf` that allows to output the contents of a double without loss of precision.

Answer (score 2):

The number of (decimal) digits you need to **uniquely** represent any `float` is by definition `std::numeric_limits<float>::maxdigits10`. The `float` format cannot distinguish between `0.0` and `0.0000` so this constant is the maximum value you'll ever need.

Now, note that I said **uniquely**. This is not **exact**. It means that if you write two different binary values, you'll get two different decimal representations. It also means that if you read back such a decimal representation, it cannot be confused with any other value, and therefore you get back the precise same binary value you had before. Usually, those two guarantees are sufficient.

[edit]
`std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10` represents the reverse concept: the largest number of decimal digits such that decimal->binary->decimal is guaranteed exact.

Comment: This should be `max_digits10` (introduced in C++11), not `digits10`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10

Answer (score 2):

Others have already commented that 23.345466467 does not exist as a float, but if your goal is just round-trip conversion of float values that do exist without accidentally changing their value slightly, you can either use `snprintf` and `strtod` with at least `DECIMAL_DIG` places (POSIX, but not plain ISO C, guarantees this round-trip to be exact) or print the float in hex instead of decimal. C99 has the `%a` format specifier for printing floats in hex, but if you can't depend on C99, it's easy to write your own. Unlike with decimal, the naive algorithm for printing hex floats works just fine. It goes like:

1. Scale by a power of 2 to put the value in the range `0x8 <= val < 0x10`. This power of 2 becomes the exponent in your result.
2. Repeatedly remove the integer portion of `val` and multiply by `0x10` to get the output digits.
3. When `val` reaches 0, you're done.

Conversion in the opposite direction is likewise easy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you case use fprintf() (from ) to convert your float into a string.
But the precision might be lost immediately after the affectation because 'flaot' and 'double' have a limited precision. Someone must confirm that.

Comment: Is this even intended to be an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to store its binary representation, as suggested by @pgm. However, you could also store it in decimal notation, but with use of period notation, like :

```
23.5095446(1545855463)
```

In this way they could be stored somehow "lossless", but it will require very careful coding.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing it so that you can re-read it later and use it as a float?  Or do you care what the string says?  As others have said you need to write the binary representation rather than the base10.  Or you can be a little tricky and do something like this

```
float f=23.345466467
int i=*(int*)&f; //re-interpret the bits in f as an int
cout << i;
```

and to read it

```
int i;
cin >> i;
float f=*(float&)&i;
```

[Standard disclamer about portability and making sure that int and float are the same size on your platform.]

This way you can output the value and read it back in without losing any precision.  But it's not human readable when it's being stored.

Answer (score -3):

The OP wants C or C++, but if you happen to need a C# solution, use the "R" numeric formatting string, as in:

```
float x = 23.345466467f;
string str = x.ToString("R");
```

Note that "R" is short for "Round-trip". More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: -1, answer for a totally different language. Doesn't help the OP at all.

Comment: Perhaps not, but it could help someone else who Googles their way onto this page looking for a C# answer (as I did). I was well aware the OP wanted C/C++, so I made it crystal clear what language I was speaking for.